# NO graph results with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-3.2

I have installed jmeter based on tutorial in `guru99.com` and now following exactly the steps from https://www.guru99.com/jmeter-performance-testing.html page but get no graph results [image: graph results].
I open jmeter in gui mode cause in the command line mode I get error `could not open testPlan.jmx`

Comment: See in jmeter.log full error. also show your test plan

Answer (score 7):

You forgot to add HTTP Request which will send the request

> Right-click on Thread Group and select: Add -> Sampler -> HTTP
>   Request.

Comment: @GayanWeerakutti if there's only one thread group, as in question, it doesn't matter

Answer (score 0):

I followed the same tutorial, I am using jmeter4, initially, I faced the same issue, then I tried importing the following suite, I did the following,

```
Check whether you are connecting to the internet via a proxy. If yes, remove the proxy.
    Open a new instance of Jmeter
    Open the PerformanceTestPlan.jmx in Jmeter
    Double Click on Thread Group -> Graph Result
    Run the Test
```

URL: https://www.guru99.com/jmeter-performance-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

You should set number of users enough to be visible on your graph and on your picture there's no HTTP Requests. In my case I've set number of users equal 20 in my Thread Groups with Ramp-Up period equal 60.

Also I've:

- added HTTP Request Defaults, HTTP Header Manager and Graph Results in the root of my Test Plan
- added two Thread Groups in the root of my Test Plan
- added 20 different HTTP Requests in both Thread Groups
- added View Results listeners in both Thread Groups

[image: graph picture]

[image: thread group configuration picture]